# Adding <a href ..> around link or mail

Tags: navigation

I have a custom module which prints html in *hook_block_view*. The text that my *hook_block_view* returns(in *block['content']*) might contain links and mail addresses.
Is there a drupal(or PHP) function that wraps the links/mail id in  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure one of your text formats to use the "Convert URLs into links" filter, then to apply that text format to some text you can use the [check_markup()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/check_markup/7) function like this:

```
// Run text through the Filtered HTML text format.
$formatted_text = check_markup($original_text, 'filtered_html');
```

You can change 'filtered_html' to be whichever text format you want to apply.
Note that it will run all the other filters of that text format on the text also.